# How can I setup the Magento cron on a Windows server?

Tags: windows, magento

I mean, I know that in windows I do have to use the Scheduled Tasks service, I just have no idea what command I should execute. Any leads will be appreciated, thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So yeah, the answer is to get the windows version of wget and use it to call the cron.php page:

"C:\Program Files(x86)\GNUWin32\bin\wget.exe" http:\mypage.com\cron.php

Adding that to the windows scheduler did the trick.

Comment: where can I find out cron.php?

Answer (score 0):

Magento is not supported on Windows. But if you were to try, maybe try running cron.php