# How to setup `Cron(Scheduled Task)` in `Magento`?

Tags: magento, scheduled-tasks

How to setup `Cron(Scheduled Task)` in `Magento`? How can I check whether `Scheduled Task` is set or not?

I am using `Magento 1.9.1` and My OS is `windows 8.1`.

I already googled for solution, but they talk about Linux machine. So please help me..

Answer (score 0):

I am not a windows guy but i did a quick search in google and got some links, please try it out,
https://support.sweettoothrewards.com/entries/21196536-Setting-up-CRON-Jobs-in-Magento

Magento documentation for cronjob

http://www.magentocommerce.com/wiki/1_-_installation_and_configuration/how_to_setup_a_cron_job

Also try [How can I setup the Magento cron on a Windows server?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10897036/how-can-i-setup-the-magento-cron-on-a-windows-server)

Answer (score 0):

Two steps.

1. Setup an Operating System scheduled task: 
   (on Linux it's a cron task, on Windows - it has to launch
   php C:[magento_path]\cron.php)
2. Create a magento scheduled task.
   An example of a primitive scheduled Magento task
   (common for any OS) is here

http://lycenok.com/magento-extensions/how-to-set-up-magento-scheduled-task/description.php